# Bash script OSX : split CSV

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have this string stored in a file :

```
ID1,A,B,,,,F
ID2,,,,D,E,F
ID3,,B,C,,,,
```

and I need to transform like this :

```
ID1,A
ID1,B
ID1,F
ID2,D
ID2,E
...
```

I tried with loop and IFS (like IFS=","; declare -a Array=($*)) whitout success.

Does someone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straight-forward in *Awk*,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{first=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i)) print first,$i}' file
```

Setting input and output field separator to `,` store the first field separately in `first` variable and print rest of the non-empty fields.

As suggested by user @PS. below you can also do,

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if(length($i)) print $1 FS $i}' file
```

Comment: Works for me ! Thank you

Comment: @PS.: well I see where you are getting at, but since it is out of the loop, I don't think the assignment makes any difference than printing `$1`directly. Appreciate the feedback though!

Comment: @PS.Even here, I am just trying to understand how much of a performance improvement does this make.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if($i != "") print $1","$i}' File

ID1,A
ID1,B
ID1,F
ID2,D
ID2,E
ID2,F
ID3,B
ID3,C
```

With `,` as the field seperator, for each line, loop from the `2nd` field to the `last` field. If the `current field` is not empty, print the `first field` (`IDx`) and the `current field` seperated by a `,`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Added an explanation now. But there was nothing serious going on there which deserved an explanation ;-)